# contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null) not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am implementing some print function for iframe now , and i am using below code:

```
 $('#printBtn').click(function(){
     var iframe = document.getElementById('previewInfoBodyFrame');
     iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
     return false;     
});
```

but i found that in firefox browser, it's not working , but for IE,chrome and safari, it works fine. searched a lot but cannot figure out how this happening. anyone can give some ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`execCommand('print')` is not supported by Firefox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand

You can use the `print()` function instead.

```
window.print() ;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.print

You might want to read this:
[Printing a (part of) webpage with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285902/printing-a-part-of-webpage-with-javascript)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this solution works for Firefox , but not working for IE, anyway , i combined this two with a browser check. now no issue.

Comment: You can check if a browser supports `execCommand('print')` like this: `document.queryCommandSupported('print')`

Answer (score 1):

with the help of naota, i fixed this issue for firefox , here is my full solution for printing iframe content, working fine for me .

```
 $('#printBtn').click(function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('previewInfoBodyFrame');
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox")!=-1){
         iframe.contentWindow.print();              
    }else{
         iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);
    }
    return false;     
 } );
```

Comment: This method seems to print whole page instead just the iframe for android chrome. Did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    if(!document.execCommand('print', false, null))
    {
        window.print();
    }
}
catch
{
    window.print();
}
```