# Firefox won't print unless I set a breakpoint?

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing

I have a method which creates an iframe, copies the contents of a textbox to that iframe, prints the iframe, then deletes the iframe:

```
function CentralPrint(controlID)
{
    var frameSet = document.createElement('iframe');

    frameSet.name = "frameSet";
    frameSet.id = "ErrorReportPrintingFrame";
    frameSet.style.position = "absolute";
    frameSet.style.top = "-1000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(frameSet);

    var frameDoc = frameSet.contentWindow ? frameSet.contentWindow : frameSet.contentDocument.document ? frameSet.contentDocument.document : frameSet.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();

    var content = document.getElementById(controlID).value.replace(/\n/gi, '<br>');

    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title><table><tr><td>');
    frameDoc.document.write(' <style type="text/css"> table tr td { font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; } </style> </head><body>');
    frameDoc.document.write(content);
    frameDoc.document.write('</td> </tr> </table> </body></html>');

    frameDoc.document.close();

    var iframe = document.getElementById("ErrorReportPrintingFrame");
    var result = iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand("print", false, null);

    if (!result)
    {
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
    }

    document.body.removeChild(frameSet);

    return false;
}
```

This works for IE 11, Chrome, and it works in Firefox *if* I set a breakpoint and step through the code.

I don't think this is relevant, but when I step through this with IE & Chrome, `result` is `true` and in Firefox, `result` is `false`.

I don't get the popup to choose my printing device unless I set a breakpoint in Firefox, though.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: I see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25323486/4065876.  Perhaps it helps.

Comment: @JoseLuis Yea that's why I get `result`. If it's false, then I call `print()` instead of `execCommand` as noted in the last bullet point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21336448/1189566)

Comment: Oh, sorry !!  :-(

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, but *why* it resolves the problem is beyond me:

```
function CentralPrint(controlID)
{
    // New variable
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

    var frameSet = document.createElement('iframe');

    frameSet.name = "frameSet";
    frameSet.id = "ErrorReportPrintingFrame";
    frameSet.style.position = "absolute";
    frameSet.style.top = "-1000000px";
    document.body.appendChild(frameSet);

    var frameDoc = frameSet.contentWindow ? frameSet.contentWindow : frameSet.contentDocument.document ? frameSet.contentDocument.document : frameSet.contentDocument;
    frameDoc.document.open();

    var content = document.getElementById(controlID).value.replace(/\n/gi, '<br>');

    frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title></title><table><tr><td>');
    frameDoc.document.write(' <style type="text/css"> table tr td { font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; } </style> </head><body>');
    frameDoc.document.write(content);
    frameDoc.document.write('</td> </tr> </table> </body></html>');

    frameDoc.document.close();

    // Use a timeout function instead of just issuing the command immediately
    setTimeout(function ()
    {
        var iframe = document.getElementById("ErrorReportPrintingFrame");

        if (isFirefox != true)
            iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand("print", false, null);
        else
            iframe.contentWindow.print();

        document.body.removeChild(frameSet);
    }, 500);

    return false;
}
```

I guess it must be some bizarre issue with the element being deleted before the print command does what it needs to do?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of issue is called a `race condition`. You are trying to get an element before it has finished loading.

Rather than use a timeout, you can add an `onLoad` event listener to `frameSet`.

```
frameSet.onload = function() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("ErrorReportPrintingFrame");
  ...
};
```

Or if you like the timeout, you can most likely reduce it to `0` and it will still work.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I tried assigning it to `frameDoc` instead, but that doesn't either. I also moved the `document.body.appendChild(frameSet);` line to be the last thing that gets executed before trying to print, thinking that maybe it was trying to print before the content actually gets written. The console tells me `TypeError: frameSet.contentDocument is null`

Comment: FireFox has a few race conditions bugs, that can normally got round with setTimeout 0. If is a bug in the browser that might be your only option