# window.print() method throwing error in Firefox Version 100.0 (64-bit)

Tags: javascript, firefox, printing, domexception

I have been using the [JavaScript print() method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-window-print-method/) for printing the content of a page. The code hasn't been changed in 2 years and it was working on Firefox until a few days ago, when I got the Version 100.0.

This is the code I have been using to print:

```
print() {
    const printableElement = Printer.createPrintableElement()
    const printableContentWindow = printableElement.contentWindow
    if (!printableContentWindow) {
      return
    }

    const { styles, html } = this.proceedContent()

    printableContentWindow.document.head.innerHTML = `${styles}`
    printableContentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html

    printableContentWindow.focus()
    printableContentWindow.print()
}

static createPrintableElement() {
    const printableElement = document.createElement('iframe')
    printableElement.width = '0'
    printableElement.height = '0'

    document.body.appendChild(printableElement)

    return printableElement
}

static collectPageStyles() {
    return [...document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"], style')].reduce(
      (acc, style) => (acc += style.outerHTML),
      ''
    )
  }

filterContentElements() {
    const { ignoreElements } = this.options
    const content = this.element

    if (ignoreElements.length === 0) {
      return content
    }

    ignoreElements.forEach((selector) => {
      const elementsToDelete = content.querySelectorAll(selector)
      elementsToDelete.forEach((node) => node.remove())
    })

    return content
}

proceedContent() {
    const styles = Printer.collectPageStyles()
    const html = this.filterContentElements().innerHTML

    return { styles, html }
}
```

I try to debug it and I realized it fails on the method `print()`, specifically on `printableContentWindow.print()`. The error it shows on browser console is this:
[image]
And when it occurs, the page to be printed is completely blank.

This code works perfectly on Chrome, Opera and Opera GX.

Any idea what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may work if you change your print function to the following:

```js
print() {
    const printableElement = Printer.createPrintableElement()
    const printableContentWindow = printableElement.contentWindow
    if (!printableContentWindow) {
      return
    }

    setTimeout(function ()
    {
       const { styles, html } = Printer.proceedContent()
    }, 100);

    printableContentWindow.document.head.innerHTML = `${styles}`
    printableContentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = html

    setTimeout(function ()
    {
      printableContentWindow.focus()
      printableContentWindow.print()
    }, 100);
}
```

This is a 'racing' bug in FireFox. I was having similar issues and found this answer, [Firefox won't print unless I set a breakpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678755/firefox-wont-print-unless-i-set-a-breakpoint), which pointed me in the right direction.