# Why would a button that invokes a custom print function break the printing on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have created a custom print function using javascript (it closely models this tutorial https://levelup.gitconnected.com/pretty-print-your-site-with-javascript-d69f63956529). When I am only overriding the 'ctrl + p' shortcut it is running acceptably, but when I add a button to invoke the function it causes both the 'ctrl + p' and the button print to give the following error 'NotSupportedError: Window.print: Clone operation for printing failed'.

This is only happening in Firefox and the code works fine in Chrome.

Below is some of the code

Javascript code

```js
const NsPrettyPrintPage = {
  print: function () {

  // create a hidden iframe named PrettyPrintFrame
  const prettyPrintIframe = document.createElement('iframe');

  prettyPrintIframe.setAttribute('id', 'PrettyPrintFrame');
  prettyPrintIframe.setAttribute('name', 'PrettyPrintFrame');
  prettyPrintIframe.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');

  // add newly created iframe to the current DOM
  document.body.appendChild(prettyPrintIframe);

  // add generated header content
  prettyPrintIframe.contentWindow.document.head.innerHTML = this.generateHeaderHtml();

  // add generated body content
  prettyPrintIframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = this.generatePrintLayout();

    document.getElementById("PrettyPrintFrame").contentWindow.print();
  },
  generatePrintLayout: function () {
    // this function houses your default header/footer details and the switch to identify your pages by

    let html = '';

        html += '<h1 class="page-header"><img src="images/logo.png"></h1>'

    html += this.calculatorResults();

    // global footer elements
    html += this.generateFooterHtml();

    return html;
  },
  generateHeaderHtml: function () {
    let headerHtml = '';

        headerHtml += '<html><body><head>';

    // loop through the styleSheets object and pull in all styles
    for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
      headerHtml += '<style>';

      try {
        for (let j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
          headerHtml += document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].cssText || '';
        }
      } catch(e) {}

      headerHtml += '</style>';
    }

    headerHtml += this.generateGlobalCss();

        headerHtml += '</head>';

    return headerHtml;
  },
  generateGlobalCss: function () {
    // add any global css you want to apply to all pretty print pages
    let css = '<style>';

    // global css
    css += 'body { padding: 40px 24px; }';
    css += 'table tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }';
    css += 'table td { vertical-align: top; padding: 4px 8px;}';
        css += '#blank_row { display: none; }';
    css += '@page { margin: 0.8cm; }';
        css += 'table thead { display: none; }';
        css += 'table td b { background-color: yellow !important; }';
    css += '</style>';

    return css;
  },
  generateFooterHtml: function () {
    let footerHtml = '</body></html>';

    return footerHtml;
  },
  calculatorResults: function() {
    let html = '';
        let resultItems = document.querySelectorAll('.table');

    // iterate over result items
    resultItems.forEach(function(item) {
     html += item.outerHTML;
    });

        html += '<table class="table table-bordered"><tr><td></td><td>Indirect Fired</td><td>Direct Fired</td><td>Hydronic Fired</td><td>Electric</td></tr>';
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>Total Project Cost</td><td><b>';
        html += document.querySelector('#final_project_cost_indirect_air').innerHTML;
        html += '</b></td>';
        html += '<td><b>';
        html += document.querySelector('#final_project_cost_open_flame').innerHTML;
        html += '</b></td>';
        html += '<td><b>';
        html += document.querySelector('#final_project_cost_hydronic').innerHTML;
        html += '</b></td>';
        html += '<td><b>';
        html += document.querySelector('#final_project_cost_electric_output').innerHTML;
        html += '</b></td></tr></table>';

    return html;
  }
};

// override Ctrl/Cmd + P
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key == "p") {
        NsPrettyPrintPage.print();
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
} , false);
```

Button I added that seems to break the printing when using firefox.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="NsPrettyPrintPage.print();"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>Print</button>
```

Update:

It appears to be working if I removed all the Javascript libraries that were included. There is an error in the Javascript when the page loads when it starts Bootstrap. The line below that says 'FormPlugins.init();'.

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            App.init();
            DashboardV2.init();
            FormSliderSwitcher.init();
            ChartNvd3.init();
            FormPlugins.init();
        });

        $('#heatcalc_form').on('keyup keypress', function(e)
        {
              var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
              if (keyCode === 13)
              {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
              }
        });
    </script>
```

That error is 'TypeError: $(...).colorpicker is not a function'.

Comment: Why is your button invoking `window.print()` if you want to use your custom print command?

Comment: Okay, so now that you changed the button's `onclick` invocation, how accurate is your question re: _'NotSupportedError: Window.print: ..._ error message?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I was testing things and forgot to change it back before I posted this question. When it said `window.print()` that button would work but the 'ctrl + p' would not.

Comment: I found a way to make it work. It appears that it is the newline characters being added to the html. That doesn't make any sense to me, so I am currently checking if my text editor, atom, is doing something funky.

Comment: I have just found a question that I believe that mine (this one) is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72219164/window-print-method-throwing-error-in-firefox-version-100-0-64-bit. It also does not have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function is working now with this code as the print function.

```js
print: function () {

  // create a hidden iframe named PrettyPrintFrame
  const prettyPrintIframe = document.createElement('iframe');

  prettyPrintIframe.setAttribute('id', 'PrettyPrintFrame');
  prettyPrintIframe.setAttribute('name', 'PrettyPrintFrame');
  prettyPrintIframe.setAttribute('style', 'display: none;');

  // add newly created iframe to the current DOM
  document.body.appendChild(prettyPrintIframe);


    setTimeout(function ()
  {
        // add generated header content
    prettyPrintIframe.contentWindow.document.head.innerHTML = NsPrettyPrintPage.generateHeaderHtml();

    // add generated body content
    prettyPrintIframe.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = NsPrettyPrintPage.generatePrintLayout();
    }, 100);

    setTimeout(function ()
  {
        document.getElementById("PrettyPrintFrame").contentWindow.print();
    }, 100);
}
```

It turned out that it was a 'racing' error. This, [Firefox won't print unless I set a breakpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44678755/firefox-wont-print-unless-i-set-a-breakpoint), answer pointed me in the right direction.